# How to marge/add two or more Python dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Lets say I have two python dictionaries:

```
dct_01 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dct_02 = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

and I want:

```
dct_03 = {'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

If both the dictionary have same key->value pair, it should remain same, if there is same key with different values it should add up.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: I've several pickle file each of them is a dictionary, and for analysis purpose I've to marge them in a single dictionary. @eyllanesc

Comment: okay, I understand the similarity between the keys of the dictionaries, but the values do not exist a logic, for example in dct_01 a "a" corresponds to 1, a dct_02 corresponds to 2, and dct_03 corresponds to 3, so you might think that 3 = 1 +2, but in the case of "c" it does not comply with the previous rule.

Comment: @eyllanesc the value for c doesn't make sense given the values for a and b.  It should be 6 as your adding the others.

Comment: @Eric That's the intuitive thing, but it's not what the OP points to, that's the reason for my question.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry, I didn't mean to tag you.  For some reason I thought you were the OP.  Sorry

Comment: If both the dictionary have same key->value pair, it should remain same, if there is same key with different values it should add up. @eeyllanesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m = {}
for i in dct_01.keys()|dct_02.keys():
   v1 = dct_01.get(i)
   v2 = dct_02.get(i)
   if v1==v2: m[i] = v1
   elif v1 is None: m[i] = v2
   elif v2 is None: m[i] = v1
   else: m[i] = v1+v2

m
{'d': 4, 'c': 3, 'a': 3, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension with a custom function. We calculate the union of dictionary keys via `set(dct_01) | set(dct_02)` and iterate over them.

```
dct_01 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dct_02 = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

def calc_val(d1, d2, k):
    val1 = d1.get(k, 0)
    val2 = d2.get(k, 0)
    if val1 == val2:
        return val1
    return val1 + val2

res = {k: calc_val(dct_01, dct_02, k) for k in set(dct_01) | set(dct_02)}

print(res)

{'b': 3, 'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dct_01 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dct_02 = {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
dct_03 = {**dct_01,**dct_02}
print(dct_03)
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful with some explanation

Comment: @MichaelS.: That's true. Though that's not a sufficient reason to recommend deletion. (It is a good reason to downvote them, of course.)